# How to restrict components in Google Maps geocoding API request URL

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I'm using google maps geocoding API to get a given town/city's latitude and longitude. I'm trying to restrict the JSON response to cities/towns within France. I have gone through the documentation which I found at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start

However the request returns me coordinates even if the location I have entered is not a city. Following is the JSON request URL I have built.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=abc&components=postal_town:abc|country:FR&key=API_KEY
```

When I use the above request it returns me the following JSON although "abc" is not a valid town.

```
    {
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "4",
               "short_name" : "4",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Rue Auber",
               "short_name" : "Rue Auber",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Paris",
               "short_name" : "Paris",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Paris",
               "short_name" : "Paris",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Île-de-France",
               "short_name" : "Île-de-France",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "France",
               "short_name" : "FR",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "75009",
               "short_name" : "75009",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "4 Rue Auber, 75009 Paris, France",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 48.87234979999999,
               "lng" : 2.3300877
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 48.8736987802915,
                  "lng" : 2.331436680291502
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 48.8710008197085,
                  "lng" : 2.328738719708498
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJh-qjtzZu5kcRrJWMR6brrZc",
         "types" : [ "atm", "bank", "establishment", "finance", "point_of_interest" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "18",
               "short_name" : "18",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Rue du 4 Septembre",
               "short_name" : "Rue du 4 Septembre",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Paris",
               "short_name" : "Paris",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Paris",
               "short_name" : "Paris",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Île-de-France",
               "short_name" : "Île-de-France",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "France",
               "short_name" : "FR",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "75002",
               "short_name" : "75002",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "18 Rue du 4 Septembre, 75002 Paris, France",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 48.869747,
               "lng" : 2.336408
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 48.8710959802915,
                  "lng" : 2.337756980291502
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 48.8683980197085,
                  "lng" : 2.335059019708498
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJnXdnRTpu5kcRJLmRDXtjBqY",
         "types" : [ "establishment", "finance", "point_of_interest" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

How can I rectify this issue?

Comment: The geocoding API always tries its best to return a result. That means you may get results that are not very good quality. You must determine how you can filter what is returned to determine if it is a good match for your needs or not.

Comment: @PaulThomasGC Does that mean trying to build the request URL with component restrictions is not an effective way to handle this issue then?

Comment: correct. You need to make the query, then perform an operation on the results to determine if what is returned is suitable for your needs. eg if it must be within certain bounds, check the lat/lng is within those bounds.